# Descending order in yajra not working properly for second page onwards

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, yajra-datatable

For ascending sort , yajra is working properly(means response has properly sorted data). I have an array like this:

suppose i have :

```
$order = $order_data [0]['dir']
$column = $order_data[0]['column']
$length = 5;
$start = 5;
```

**My Table datatable with id as ascending goes like this :**

```
[
0=>["Id"=>"111", "name"=>"jack", "age"=>"23"]
1=>["Id"=>"112", "name"=>"harry", "age"=>"12"]
2=>["Id"=>"113", "name"=>"babu", "age"=>"23"]
3=>["Id"=>"114", "name"=>"ravi", "age"=>"43"]
4=>["Id"=>"115", "name"=>"suman", "age"=>"45"]
5=>["Id"=>"116", "name"=>"david", "age"=>"54"]
6=>["Id"=>"117", "name"=>"kiran", "age"=>"53"]
7=>["Id"=>"118", "name"=>"arjay", "age"=>"78"]
8=>["Id"=>"119", "name"=>"alien", "age"=>"23"]
]
```

**My back end implementation is this:**

```
//$results contains the results after sorting
$results = $model->getPeopleSortedById($start, $length, $order);

$dataForDT = new Collection();
foreach ($results as $ds) {
    $dataForDT->push($ds);
}

return Datatables::of($dataForDT)
    ->with(['recordsTotal' => (int)$totalRecords, 'recordsFiltered' => (int)$totalRecords])
    ->make('true');
```

**I am getting response for test cases :**

Test case : 1

```
Response: data:[["Id"=>"116", "name"=>"david", "age"=>"54"],
["Id"=>"117", "name"=>"kiran", "age"=>"53"], 
["Id"=>"118", "name"=>"arjay", "age"=>"78"],
["Id"=>"119", "name"=>"alien", "age"=>"23"]]

order[0][column]:0
order[0][dir]:asc
start:5
length:5
```

Test case : 2

```
Response : data:[] /* should have been [
["Id"=>"114", "name"=>"ravi", "age"=>"43"],
["Id"=>"113", "name"=>"babu", "age"=>"23"],
["Id"=>"112", "name"=>"harry", "age"=>"12"],
["Id"=>"111", "name"=>"jack", "age"=>"23"]] */

    order[0][column]:0
    order[0][dir]:desc
    start:5
    length:5
```

**For temporary solution I am doing this :**

```
//$results contains the results after sorting
$results = $model->getPeopleSortedById($start, $length, $order);

$dataForDT = new Collection();
$mDataSupport = 'true';
$orderFirst = 'false';

if ($order == "desc") {
    $orderFirst = 'false';
}

//temporary fix start
if($order=="asc"){
    $temp = ["Id"=>"", "name"=>"", "age"=>""];
} else {
    $temp = ["Id"=>"999999999", "name"=>"zzzzzzzzzzz", "age"=>"99999999"];
}

$results = array_pad($results , (-((int)$start + count($results))), $temp);
//temporary fix end

foreach ($results as $ds) {
    $dataForDT->push($ds);
}

return Datatables::of($dataForDT)
    ->with(['recordsTotal' => (int)$totalRecords, 'recordsFiltered' => (int)$totalRecords])
    ->make('true');
```

Now data is coming properly with the use of bold lines. 
Data not showing for second page onwards for desc. 
Is it a bug of Yajra?

PS: using v6.27.0 of Yajra. This issue might not be there in previous versions.